# Does IBM Watson support "Speaker diarization"/"Speaker Recognition"?

Tags: speech-recognition, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I was playing with IBM Watson's speech-to-text demo at https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/. I uploaded an audio file with 2 speakers. Watson returned transcribed text without speaker identifier. There's no indication of which word was spoken by which speaker. Does IBM Watson support "Speaker diarization"/"Speaker Recognition"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are working on [**Speaker Diarization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_diarisation). No ETA yet but hopefully it will be soon.
As it is today, the service treats the audio as if it was the same speaker

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not, unfortunately.